# codeigniter insert : special characters trims my string values

Tags: database, codeigniter, character-encoding, insert

I have a problem executing insert commands that are loaded from a text file. I use codeIgniter "file" helper to load an sql line then I perform a simple db->query(`content of my file`). The problem is when the sql is loaded from a file the special character trims the rest of the string.

Here is an example that works

```
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES("<p>There is <strong>no special character</strong> in this string</p>");
```

Example that **will not work**

```
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES("<p>this character <em>é</em> is a <strong>special character</strong></p>");
```

In the second example, only `"<p> this character <em>"` will be saved. This is weird because if I execute the same line in phpMyAdmin it works fine.

Anyone knows why this happens? or what I do wrong?

Thanks

---

Here is a simple "step to reproduce".

Simple table :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`test` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A file "application/view/text.txt" that contains :

```
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES("<p>this character <em>é</em> is a <strong>special character</strong></p>");
```

The code I use to perform the insert

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$loaded_sql = read_file(BASEPATH . "../application/views/test.txt");
$this->db->query($loaded_sql);
```

My database config

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

CI Config

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: are your text files UTF8 encoded?

Comment: Sure I didn't check that. File was encoded ANSI (default notepad encoding I guess). I saved the file as UTF-8 but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the error CI shows : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ï»¿INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES("

this character Ã© is a spe' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it. Needed to use "utf8_encode()" when reading the file to unsure that special character gets encoded properly. Text file must be encoded in ANSI (default notepad encoding). If file is UTF-8 or UNICODE it won't work!

Code that resolved the problem :

```
$loaded_sql = utf8_encode( read_file(BASEPATH . "../application/views/test.txt") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use before inserting record in table.

```
$this->db->db_set_charset('latin1', 'latin1_swedish_ci');
```

Make sure  you have same setting in table & table column.